# Creating separate line feature from multi-line feature in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, features, splitting

I am working with road network data and I have a large amount of lines that are not connected but are classified as the same feature.  I want to select one or more of those lines and create a new feature in order to rename and connect it with the correct road feature.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I've found a workaround that requires saving the selected feature as a layer, running 'single parts to multiparts', selecting the features I want, creating another layer, then merging that layer with the original (which creates a 4th layer).  Not exactly efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Multipart Split](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/splitmultipart/) plugin for that.

Turn the layer to edit mode. Select the "problematic" feature(s) and click the multipart split icon  (Available in the advanced digitizing toolbar) to transform the multipart features in several single feature.